# How do I post XML?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, api

How do I post a XML and get the response status from the response?

I want to post

```
<myExampleRequest><myValue>xyz</myValue></myExampleRequest>
```

to http://domain.com/GetStatus.aspx

The page responds with

```
<myExampleResponse><status>True</status><Message></Message></myExampleResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best not to do too much of this yourself.  Use an HTTP Client library like [HttpClient](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient) or libcurl.  Some examples of HttpClient that might help you get started are [here](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/examples.php).

O'Reilly's [HTTP: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925090) is great for background.  I also like [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260) (which has examples written in libcurl).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set your `Content-type` header to text/xml, then echo out your response:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $xml_response;
```

Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or cURL to process the response into a string, and use some sort of XML parser like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse the response to get `<status>`.